# What's wrong with RabbitMQ in Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq, spring-boot

I am trying to run the sample project from [Create a RabbitMQ message receiver](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/).But it's throwing exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'exclude' is of type [Class[]], but [String[]] was expected. Cause: 
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes.doGet(AnnotationAttributes.java:117)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes.getStringArray(AnnotationAttributes.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:63)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:386)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:683)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:944)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:933)
    at Application.main(Application.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-messaging-rabbitmq</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-releases</id>
                <name>Spring Releases</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-releases</id>
                <name>Spring Releases</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Here is my class file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    final static String queueName = "spring-boot";

    @Autowired
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Waiting five seconds...");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, "Hello from RabbitMQ!");
        receiver().getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with me?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was the problem with my IDE. I just reimport all the maven dependency and able to solved it.Thanks to [Nicolsas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson)
and 
[Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564005/nicolas-labrot)